# How can i change on click function every time i got an error

Tags: javascript, html

I want first click to make the getNumberBtn to be getNumberBtnn
and the second one to get it back to getNumberBtn function.
When I click, the function run but doesn't change the onclick property

```js
var equation = 0;

function getNumberBtn() {
  document.getElementById("apply").onclick = getNumberBtnn();
  equation = equation + x;
}
function getNumberBtnn() {
  document.getElementById("apply").onclick = getNumberBtn();
  equation = equation + x;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="1000">

  <button id="apply" onclick=getNumberBtn()>Apply</button>

</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is 'x' and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign the function to `onclick`, you are actually calling the function and thus creating an infinite recursive.

You can just assign the function name to `onclick` -

```js
var equation = 0;

function getNumberBtn() {
  document.getElementById("apply").onclick = getNumberBtnn;
  equation = equation + document.getElementById("number").value;
  console.log('Called getNumberBtn');
}

function getNumberBtnn() {
  document.getElementById("apply").onclick = getNumberBtn;
  equation = equation + document.getElementById("number").value;
  console.log('Called getNumberBtnn');
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="1000">

  <button id="apply" onclick=getNumberBtn()>Apply</button>

</div>
```

But I would suggest you use `DOM event registration` instead using `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`-

```js
var equation = 0;

var apply = document.getElementById("apply");

apply.addEventListener('click', getNumberBtn);

function getNumberBtn() {
  apply.removeEventListener('click', getNumberBtn);
  apply.addEventListener('click', getNumberBtnn);
  equation = equation + document.getElementById("number").value;
  console.log('Called getNumberBtn');
}

function getNumberBtnn() {
  apply.removeEventListener('click', getNumberBtnn);
  apply.addEventListener('click', getNumberBtn);
  equation = equation + document.getElementById("number").value;
  console.log('Called getNumberBtnn');
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="1000">

  <button id="apply">Apply</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign the event handler but the result of the function.

As I said in my comment, remove the () from the end of the function you assign.

Also you do not assign anything to `x`

However I suggest you do this instead:

1. Use eventListener
2. Use a function to decide which function to call
3. Have the list on functions in an object
4. Actually have different functions

```js
let equation = 0;
const funcs = {

  "btn": function(x) {
    equation += x; // for example
    console.log("btn", equation)
  },
  "btnn": function(x) {
    equation *= x; // for example
    console.log("btnn", equation)
  }
}

document.getElementById("apply").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const func = tgt.dataset.func
  tgt.dataset.func = func === "btn" ? "btnn" : "btn"; // toggle the function
  funcs[func](+document.getElementById("number").value); // call the chose function with a value
})
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="1000">

  <button type="button" data-func="btn" id="apply">Apply</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `()` from in front of function name while editing `onclick` property

```
function getNumberBtn() {
  document.getElementById("apply").onclick = getNumberBtnn;
  equation = equation + x;
}
function getNumberBtnn() {
  document.getElementById("apply").onclick = getNumberBtn;
  equation = equation + x;
}
```